# Disabling Alt+F4 in a Powershell form

Tags: forms, powershell, keyboard, shortcut

I've written a powershell script which displays a form using `System.Windows.Forms`.  I've already disabled the control box and all other ways that this form can be closed via the mouse.  But I can't find a way of preventing the form closing by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

i.e. Code snippet looks like this:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Restart Required"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Topmost = $True
$objForm.MinimizeBox = $false
$objForm.MaximizeBox = $false
$objForm.FormBorderStyle = "Fixed3d" 
$objForm.ControlBox = $false
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), there are articles about overriding the `FormClosing` eventhandler in VB, C#, etc and .  But I'm not sure how to implement similar logic into Powershell (if it's at all possible).

Comment: Oh come on, a "Restart Required" box that you can't close? This is so user hostile I hope it's impossible.

Comment: If a restart is required, why not launch `shutdown -r` instead?

Comment: We should migrate this to UX so it can be explained *why* this is such a bad choice.

Comment: Did you not read the part where I say "code snippet", as opposed to the full code?  My script is almost 1000 lines with many different forms and buttons.  For sake of brevity and relevance, I only posted the minimum code to display the form as everything else is irrelevant.  Do you feel a need for me to add a button to please you, or go into the full user requirements as to why I cannot simply do a "shutdown.exe -r" or "Restart-Computer" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set forms keypreview to true

```
$form1_KeyDown=[System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler]{
    #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs]

    if ($_.Alt -eq $true -and $_.KeyCode -eq 'F4') {
        $script:altF4Pressed = $true;           
    }
}

$form1_FormClosing=[System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler]{
    #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs]

    if ($script:altF4Pressed)
    {
        if ($_.CloseReason -eq 'UserClosing') {
            $_.Cancel = $true
            $script:altF4Pressed = $false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sjcnyc.  Unfortunately that code snippet doesn't appear to prevent alt-f4 from closing the form.

Comment: Make sure you set the Form's "KeyPreview" to true.  $form1.KeyPreview = $True

Comment: Thanks sjcnyc!  That code on pastebin works well!  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: The key bit from your pastebin code that you omitted from this post was adding the event handler to the form, which was just: 
`    $form1.add_FormClosing($form1_FormClosing)
     $form1.add_KeyDown($form1_KeyDown)`

Comment: can you please update the right solution here, my form is still closing when alt+f4 is pressed. So the answer is not correct.